# matplotlib: share x-axis for two barcharts, each with 4 groups

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to create a figure with two barcharts using matplotlib. Each barchart has 4 groups of bars. The current python code I am using is as follows:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
bar_width=0.15

rects1 = plt.bar(index, group0, bar_width,
                  alpha=opacity,
                 color='b',
                  label='1')

rects2 = plt.bar(index + bar_width, group1, bar_width,
                  alpha=opacity,
                 color='r',
                  label='2')

rects3 = plt.bar(index + bar_width+bar_width, group2, bar_width,
                  alpha=opacity,
                 color='c',
                  label='3')

rects4 = plt.bar(index + bar_width+bar_width+bar_width, group3, bar_width,
                  alpha=opacity,
                 color='m',
                  label='4')
```

After some formatting, the plot I obtain is as follows:

[image]

Now, I have two such barcharts and I want them to share the x-axis.

[image]

I can't figure out a way to achieve this. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007016/matplotlib-creating-two-stacked-subplots-with-shared-x-axis-but-separate-y-ax ?

Comment: Not really, the problem in my case is that I can't use axes.bar() because for each axes, I have multiple bars to be plotted.

Comment: You can call multiple time bar on the same axe, it will do the same as calling multiple time `plt.bar`

Comment: Thanks, it works. Posting my solution as an answer below for future references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Mel, calling bar() multiple times on the same axes worked in this case. Working code for this:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(2,1,sharex=True)
ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
a=ax1.bar(index, rating0,width=0.15,alpha=opacity,
                 color='c'
                  )
index=map(lambda x:x+0.15, index)
b=ax1.bar(index,rating1,width=0.15,alpha=opacity,
                 color='r')
index=map(lambda x:x+0.15, index)
c=ax1.bar(index,rating2,width=0.15,alpha=opacity,
                 color='y')
index=map(lambda x:x+0.15, index)
d=ax1.bar(index,rating3,width=0.15,alpha=opacity,
                 color='m')

index=map(lambda x:x-0.45, index)
ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2, sharex=ax1)
ax2.bar(index, rating0paris,width=0.15,alpha=opacity,
                 color='c')
index=map(lambda x:x+0.15, index)
ax2.bar(index,rating1paris,width=0.15,alpha=opacity,
                 color='r')
index=map(lambda x:x+0.15, index)
ax2.bar(index,rating2paris,width=0.15,alpha=opacity,
                 color='y')
index=map(lambda x:x+0.15, index)
ax2.bar(index,rating3paris,width=0.15,alpha=opacity,
                 color='m')

for axes in ax:
    format_axes(axes)
```

Also attaching the obtained figure for reference:
[image: subplots with barcharts]